# URL Session Post with form-data parameter in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am trying to POST a parameter using form-data in swift.
I want to pass a mobile number with url session in form-data format. but I can't able to send data properly . please help me to pass data on form-data format in url session.

code I have Tried:

```
func registerService(){

    print("register tapped")

    let parameters: [String: Any]  = [
        "mobile" : mobileNumber
    ]
    let url = URL(string: "http://54.251.198.30/api/user/login")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    req.addValue("multipart/form-data : \(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
  
    req.httpBody = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: parameters)

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if response != nil {
             print(response)
        }
         if let jsonResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginBase.self, from: data!) {
                                print(jsonResponse)
        
                            }else{
                                print("error")
                            }

    }).resume()
}
```

I have added an image which parameter I want to pass. [you Can see Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzksa.png)

thanks for your response

Comment: You have a typo in the name of the header you're adding to, it should be "Content-Type".  I don't know if this is the full answer to your question, but it's definitely going to contribute to it.

Answer (score -4):

**I have modified your function parameter as well as request-body in the correct syntax. Now you can use as follows:-**

```
  func Register(){
      print("register tapped")

    let parameters: [String: Any]  = ["mobile" : mobileNumber] as Dictionary<String, Any>

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://54.251.198.30/api/user/login")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print(response!)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Question is about `form-data` format but you are providing example with JSON

Comment: it's not about form-data